# How to parse a dynamic json using Gson?

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have been developing an android app using some **JSON** got from server, things were doing well until I got **JSON** like the one below:

```
"Jack": {
    "age": 20,
    "gender": "male" 
},
"Tom": {
    "age": 40,
    "gender": "male",
    "avatar": "some image url"
}
```

As you can see, key **avatar** is not always there, so how am I supposed to parse this kind of json using Gson.

Any helps would be appreciated.

Comment: What problem do you have with your current code/approach? And, for that matter, what IS your current code?

Comment: If you user object has a `String avatar`, it will be null when you convert the JSON for `jack`

Answer (score -1):

I using [jsonschema](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) format Json to Gson and add `org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28`in gradle for annotation.

Example

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<Model>>() {}.getType();
List<Model> data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonResponse, listType);
```